# Vim Fails to Highlight PHP Comments Correctly

Tags: php, vim

I am relative new user to Vim and had syntax highlighting working fully in Vim, but then my box died and I had to re-install everything, now I have the following problem when editing PHP files in Vim:

[image]

My .vimrc is available as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/noah-goodrich/9166600).

**UPDATE** :set syntax returns syntax=php

php --version outputs as:

```
PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.1 (cli) (built: Dec 12 2013 04:24:35) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2013, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

How do I fix Vim so that it highlights PHP correctly?

Comment: are you sure it's using the php rules for that? what does `:set syntax` show you?

Comment: It seems like there's a problem with inline comments after lines with a semi-colon. You likely have some kind of custom highlighting string that is matching improperly. This could be in your colorscheme or ftplugin file.

Comment: @Conner - What is an ftplugin file?

Comment: See `:h ftplugin`. It might be in one of your plugins. Try commenting out the Bundle lines to see if it helps. If it does uncomment until the problem comes back.

Comment: Another way to diagnose is to use the example under `:help synID()` to figure out what syntax group is active when the highlighting is off, and then `:verbose syn list badPhpSyntaxGroup` to see where it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out which syntax group causes the wrong highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. When you have the name of the offending syntax group, you can investigate where it comes from; (the last lines of) `:scriptnames` may help.